# How can I make a battery pack with 6 18650 Li-ion that is USB rechargeable?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion

I'm new to electronics and DIY stuf but I wanted to make a Bluetooth speaker and there for I need a battery pack. I looked up a lot of information on the internet but couldn't find how I could recharge them with one (micro-)USB connection and what I should use therefor. These are the basic plans I made already based on what I already found: [image]

*The blue cable is an audio cable

These are links to the parts:

- 2 [Audio Drivers](https://www.soundimports.eu/en/nd65-8-2-1-2-aluminum-cone-full-range-driver.html) (€50)
- [Amplifier Board](https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/OEP30Wx2-Module-Class-D-Digital-Power-Amplifier-Board-Replace-TDA8932/32761426446.html) (€3)
- [Bluetooth USB adapter](https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/Hot-3-5mm-USB-Wireless-Bluetooth-Music-Audio-Car-Handsfree-Receiver-Adapter-White-Color-Free-Shipping/32354712297.html) (€3)
- [DC-DC Isolating Converter](https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/1-ST-B0505S-1W-DC-DC-5-V-Voeding-Module-4-Pin-Ge-soleerde-Converter-Z3/32839664649.html?src=google&albch=search&acnt=479-062-3723&isdl=y&aff_short_key=UneMJZVf&albcp=266121556&albag=7593673036&slnk=&trgt=aud-165594907443%3Adsa-42862830006&plac=&crea=64152518716&netw=g&device=c&mtctp=b&memo1=1t1&aff_platform=google&gclid=CjwKCAjwgr3ZBRAAEiwAGVssnZ9sSXOyI3qZCMsL632txydAAeVumKxQ9YLAgyb1DJQTx7CujvYJRxoCuCAQAvD_BwE) (€1)
- [Step down voltage converter](https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/Mini-DC-6-5-28V-to-DC-5V-MP1584-3A-DC-DC-Step-down-Converter-Power/32792537469.html) (€2)
- [Potentiometer/volume](https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/High-Quality-B50K-50K-Ohm-Dual-Linear-Taper-Volume-Control-Potentiometer-Switch/32736114703.html?src=google&albch=search&acnt=479-062-3723&isdl=y&aff_short_key=UneMJZVf&albcp=266121556&albag=7593673036&slnk=&trgt=aud-165594907443%3Adsa-42862830006&plac=&crea=64152518716&netw=g&device=c&mtctp=b&memo1=1t1&aff_platform=google&gclid=CjwKCAjwgr3ZBRAAEiwAGVssnRXtSaU5Kt-V1dRvTRXnt1Sx1AHFHQXfzEmDZfQ_cCE6ohr_aNTTpBoC46AQAvD_BwE) (€1)
- 6×[Lithium Ion battery](https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/Panasonic-Li-ion-18650-Rechargeable-Batteries-3-7V-3200mAh-Lithium-Battery-for-3-7-v-Power/32869790034.html?spm=a2g0z.search0104.3.8.4a337f66R6olb5&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10152_10151_10065_10344_10068_10342_5722912_10343_10340_5722612_10341_10696_5722812_10084_10083_10618_5722712_10304_10307_10820_10821_10302_10843_10059_306_100031_10103_10624_10623_10622_10621_10620_5722512,searchweb201603_2,ppcSwitch_5&algo_expid=2aa6bc59-8646-47fa-a1b5-cc305d64d102-1&algo_pvid=2aa6bc59-8646-47fa-a1b5-cc305d64d102&transAbTest=ae803_1&priceBeautifyAB=0) (€31)

Would this work and would this last in time?

Comment: Possibly, but few will dig though the datasheets for you. Post the relevant specs.

Comment: We discourage broad, open-ended design review questions here on EE.SE: The answer(s) tend to become long strings of unrelated edits and/or comments. While this might help you with your immediate problems, it is of no value to the site overall. We DO allow design review questions in which you explain your choices and then focus on a few points about which you still have doubts. To get a better feel of what is or is not acceptable, search for "design review" on the meta site.

Answer (score 1):

Your portable boombox project looks fine theoretically, except the battery part.

If you want 22.2 V out of six cells, you should connect the cells in-series, and draw the schematics in-series, not in parallel. And use something more sophisticated than the single-cell TP4056, unless you plan to charge each of six cells individually, one by one, and then plug the pre-charged cells into a series battery holder. It is not clear from your how do you plan to charge the cells.

The 6-cell Li-Ion battery should have total capacity of 22.2 * 3.2 = 71 W-h, while your amplifier has 2x15W (30W) power. So, depending on how loud you are planning to play it, say at 50% peak, your battery should last about 4-5 hours.